# Once I delete a filter everything disappear in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript, pug

Once i have selected a filter and I want to delete it, it delete the filter in the select "box" but everything disappear but it should display everything filterless like when I run de page for the first time.

I can't show you the web page (professional secret lol) but here are the 2 methods i'm trying (Jade):

```
select(ng-model='vm.choosenDepartment', ng-options='item.id as item.label for item in refs.departmentList track by item.id'
   option(value='')
```

and :

```
select(ng-model='vm.choosenDepartment', ng-options='item.id as item.label for item in refs.departmentList track by item.id')
button(ng-click='vm.forceUnknownOption()') Effacer
```

here is the code of `vm.forceUnknownOption()` in the controller (coffeeScript):

```
vm.forceUnknownOption = ->
    vm.choosenDepartment = 'undefined'
    return
```

I'm not sure if it's usefull to show what is inside the variables as soon as I just want to delete the filter but if it is tell me and I will edit the post.

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :

```
  vm.forceUnknownOption = ->
    delete vm.choosenDepartment
    return
```

We can't use `'undefined'` because if I do `undefined = 'toto'` i'll have toto everywhere. So I have to use the keyword `delete`